# how do I solve the overflow error : math range error

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, scipy

I am getting an overflow error

```
import numpy as np

pi = np.pi

from scipy.integrate import quad
from math import exp

hbar = 1.055e-34
boltz = 1.381e-23
c = 2.998e8

def z(x):
    return (x**3)/(exp(x)-1)

B=quad(z,0,np.inf)       
A= ((boltz**4)*B)/(4*(pi**2)*(c**2)*(hbar**3))

print (A)
```

It is giving me an overflow error in line 11, i.e `return (x**3)/(exp(x)-1)`

Answer (score 0):

You're hitting machine precision and python is freaking out.

```
>>> def z(x):
...     return (x**3)/(exp(x)-1)
...
>>> z(709)
4.336616682334302e-300
>>> z(710)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 2, in z
OverflowError: math range error
```

Just integrate up to ~700 and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.exp` instead of `math.exp`: it will raise a Warning for large numbers and return `np.inf` (which results in `1/np.inf = 0`), instead of raising an `OverFlowError`

```
def z(x):
    return (x**3)/(np.exp(x)-1)    #replace math.exp by np.exp

B, err =quad(z,0,np.inf)  # add the err, or use B=quad(...)[0] as quad will also return the integration error
A= ((boltz**4)*B)/(4*(pi**2)*(c**2)*(hbar**3))
print(A)
>> 5.668949306250541e-08
```

Comment: import numpy as np
pi = np.pi
from scipy.integrate import quad
#from math import exp

hbar = 1.055e-34
boltz = 1.381e-23
c = 2.998e8

def z(x):
    return (x**3)/(np.exp(x)-1)    

B, err =quad(z,0,np.inf)[0]  

A= (float(boltz**4)*B)/(4*(pi**2)*(c**2)*(hbar**3))
print(A)                                                                                                                                            It is giving an error 
 , line 14, in <module>
    B, err =quad(z,0,np.Inf)[0]

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable float object

Comment: edited: the [0] subscript was not needed when unpacking the two values.